# Magento 2 : Search page has not showing exact result

Tags: magento2.2, catalogsearch

I have two products

1. Product name : Test Product and sku: dp-2200
2. Product name : Test Product2 and sku: dp-3000

When I search for: "dp-2200 test" then it will return both products in the results. After some RnD I changed `search_request.xml` file and changed the clause="must" instead of "Should" in the XML file but after that I have showing no result.

So this above solution is check full string but I need to check all attribute value in product.

I just need to show first product only when searching for "dp-2200 test" keyword.

Any idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

@Camit1dk, Have you fixed the issue? I am facing same issue after migrating website from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3

Comment: no, i have use 3rd party extension for that.

Comment: your issue was resolved by extension? Can you please share extension name or vendor name?

Comment: i am not sure but i think we have use mirasvit Sphinx Search Ultimate  extension. you can also test your search criteria on this extension demo link .

Comment: one more thing is , this issue is not generate because of migration. its default magento behaviour.

Comment: You mean, this is magento bug, But I didn't get question related this, if it is magento bug.

Comment: I think it is normal magento search behaviour. The search from magento is very bad

Answer (score 0):

It's working if want not Exact SKU Search then find this code in the vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml

Find :

Replace with

-->

Result: